# Node.js app crashed on uploading a picture

Tags: javascript, express, blogs, nodemon

I am building a Node.js app for a blog website using a YouTube video and I was doing literally the same thing as that person was doing. But I’m getting the errors below:

```
nodemon] starting `node server.js`
listening......
D:\Personal Projects\blogs\server.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Personal Projects\blogs\public\uploads\1697269891291img5.png'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\Personal Projects\\blogs\\public\\uploads\\1697269891291img5.png'
}



Node.js v18.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The image names actually given in folder is img5.png but in error message it gives a list of numbers before the actual number This appears only when I’m trying to upload a picture on my website. Until then it runs

[Link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/NIHAL100102/blogs)

I have shared the GitHub link for the project above, I would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: The path `D:\Personal Projects\blogs\public\uploads\1697269891291img5.png` seems to be wrong.

Comment: You should add as much details for your question here, rather than linking your GitHub, no one will check that unfortunately. Add screenshots of your folder structure/file directories, and codes of any other configurations like package.json, etc

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please provide the relevant parts of your code here, not the whole repo